# Converged early at 10 iterations CreateML

Tags: swift, machine-learning, coreml, createml, turi-create

Am training image classifier dataset via CreateML but its keeps stopping at 10 iteration saying converged early at 10 iterations.
My Training accuracy varied from 80-88 and validation of 70.2% for 10 iterations.
Evaluation Precision was 59%.
Although i entered 100 iteration in settings. It isnt going beyond 10.

Comment: I think that means it was unable to learn any more, so it stopped early. You may not have enough images in your dataset.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: I had over 7,000 images in dataset...